# Which books can I study (learn) better the topics about convergence in $\Bbb R^{n}$ and euclidean space?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I have question.

Which books can I study (learn) better the topics about convergence in $\Bbb R^{n}$ and euclidean space ? Please can you give me an advice some book names? 
Thank you!

Comment: Convergence is always coordinatewise.

Comment: What? I just want to learn a book name about these @berci

Comment: @B11: This should probably be Community Wiki. Do you have any objections to making it CW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See chapter 16 of [Mathematical Analysis II](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=XF8W9W-eyrgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r#v=onepage&q&f=false)  by  V. A. Zorich. A [Universitext](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540874539) colection of Springer Edition. A wonderful book.

[image: Cover of the book written by V. A. Zorich]
<sub>(source: [springer.com](https://images.springer.com/cda/content/image/cda_displayimage.jpg?SGWID=0-0-16-96136-0))</sub>

This chapter and the chapter beyond are dedicated to Uniform Convergence and Basic Operations of Analysis.

Comment: No need for such a large image!

Comment: There is an image of the cover on the linked page. Is it beneficial to include an image (much less, such a large image) here?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Analysis in Euclidean Space](http://archive.org/details/AnalysisInEuclideanSpace) by Hoffman, [reissued](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486458040.html) by Dover.

Comment: Hmm this is good book. I looked at this. Well, what else?

Comment: I reviewed this book for the MAA-I think it's the best one there is for this particular aspect of convergence.

Comment: The MAA review is available at http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/19/?pa=reviews&sa=viewBook&bookId=68237.

Answer (score 0):

Espaces Vectoriels Normés et Topologie:Rédigé par Yannick Privat.

Topologie pour la Licence: Cours et exercices Clemens Berger1